# Inside MS Flow how i can build an email array from a "People or Group" which accept users and groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow

I have the following field inside my sharepoint form:-

[image]

and i want to send approval emails to all the group/s members (if any) + the individual user/s (if any):-

[image]

now i read this link @ https://alextofan.com/2019/10/02/how-to-send-approval-requests-to-groups-in-microsoft-flow/ which mention that i can get the members of an office 365 group, but in my case i need this to be dynamic + i need to build a list of email addresses for the following:-

1. Individual user/s (If any)
2. Office 365 group/s member/s (If any)
3. SharePoint group/s members (If any)

?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is way too many requests for one flow. The real problem is, flow cannot tell the differences between these receipts.
But we can start with the individual tasks:

1. A **SharePoint group** does not have a valid Email address to locate so it will not be accepted as a receipt in the flow.

   As a workaround, you can call REST API to [Get Users from the SharePoint group using Microsoft Flow](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2020/05/05/get-users-from-the-sharepoint-group-using-microsoft-flow/).
2. For **M365 groups**, you can change the `Group Id` in the "List group members" action to **custom value** and then use the following expression:    `last(split(triggerBody()?['Approvers']?['Claims'], '|'))`

   It extracts the `Group Id` from the Dynamic Value `Approvers`.
3. For **individual users** in the column, just use `Approvers.Email` in `Assigned to` field in the “Start and wait for an approval” action and skip all these processes.

Comment: so first thing i need to split the entities inside the Approvers field, and then for each entity to try the above 3 steps on each of them? not sure how this will work in reality? can you advice more please?

Comment: @JohnJohn No, not inside the Approvers field, you need to do the split before the Approval process, by using a Condition action, for example.